# Best OCR For Hexdumps

Tags: ascii, ocr, xxd

I am looking for a way in which it is possible to extract the left side of the image (the non ascii characters) here, reliably, using OCR. I have a number of images in a similar format, also showing hex data, that i would like to extract.

Would anyone be able to reccomend a way to extract the text from these images?
[image]

[image]

Ideally, the output for first line would be :

0005C850 00 00 00 00 etc.

and output for fourth line would be something like:

0005C8AA ED 93 A7 8E etc.

Comment: Could you give more details about your problem? What is the context?

Comment: I like this question, but am voting to close because it seems to be asking for a tool recommendation, which is off topic.

Comment: I wouldn't say that's explicitly off topic. I am looking for a programmatic way or tool that is able to extract the text from these images.

Comment: use https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract  to OCR Full Image and apply some condition to return only your needed token

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A legendary program has been written that does this. - https://github.com/eighttails/ProgramListOCR . For Windows systems, i ran on a VM.

Was hard to find.

First you want to convert your image to 400% of the size:

convert -resize 400% source.png source.png

Make it grayscale:

convert source.png  -colorspace Gray  destination.png

Change it into a tiff file:

convert destination.png destination.tiff

You then process it using this software.